# Synchronizing two databases that belongs to different networks

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization

I'm new to the to Sync Framework, I have done basic prototyping on it and all went ok. However, I have a scenario where I need to synchronize two databases that belongs to separate network. I have done my part of educating myself by browsing thru several websites and most discussions were of two databases with direct connections. Do you have any existing prototypes that tackles synchronization between to MS SQL 2008 R2 DB servers that belongs to separate networks? Any help from you would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The sync framework is not the only option. Have you looked at Db replication?

Comment: I am no expert but [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2010/09/24/how-to-sync-large-sql-server-databases-to-sql-azure.aspx) can give you a starting point. Also, not sure why you classified this under WCF tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can find samples using WCF here:

[Database Sync: SQL Server and SQL Compact N-Tier with WCF](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-Sync-SQL-Server-7e88adab)

[Database Sync:SQL Server and SQL Express N-Tier with WCF](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-SyncSQL-Server-e97d1208)

[Windows Azure Sync Service Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Azure-Sync-Service-60293622)

[Walkthrough of Windows Azure Sync Service Sample](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/walkthrough-of-windows-azure-sync-service-demo.aspx)

I would recommend the Azure Sync Service Sample since this has a corresponding walkthrough. if you're not using SQL Azure, just ignore the Azure related codes/deployment steps.